# Install gems on docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rubygems, bundler, docker-compose

I develop an app using rails and Docker. I faced an issue: when I run

```
docker-compose -f dcom-dev.yml run --user $(id -u)  web gem install google-api-client
```

it runs good, but if I write to my Gemfile `gem 'google-api-client'` and then run

```
docker-compose -f dcom-dev.yml run --user $(id -u)  web bundle install
```

it failes with several warnings like this:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /.gem/ruby/2.3.0/cache/memoist-0.14.0.gem
```

and an error like this:

```
An error occurred while installing memoist (0.14.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install memoist -v '0.14.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

If I run `gem install` manually, it works fine, but `bundle install` throws error about another gem (little-plugger). If I install the second gem manually, bundler throws message about the first gem (memoist) again and it repeats again and again. What could I do with this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helped me to remove `--user $(id -u)`.